# XUnit dotnet test parallel threads amount

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, automated-tests, xunit

How can I specify amount of threads while using dotnet test

Xunit 2.4.1
Xunit.runner.visualstudio 2.4.5
netcoreapp 3.1

The issue: I have a Job that is running tests using dotnet test and I have different agent with different performance capacity. For example One machine can handle 10 threads and the other only 6. Now the amount of threads specified in xunit.runner.json file. Could I specify amount of threads from the console? or can I specify the config file to use?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [xUnit docs](https://xunit.net/docs/configuration-files#file), you should reference `xunit.runner.json` within your `csproj` file like this:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="xunit.runner.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Doing so should pick up the config file in all cases (CLI, UI, etc.).

Comment: Yeap it's how I use it now, but can I have 2 different configs at the same time and specify which should be used before run started?

Comment: Yes, you can use the `Condition` attribute ({see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions?view=vs-2022))