# How do I configure the concurrency level of XUnit through the the `dotnet test` CLI?

Tags: xunit, dotnet-test

How do I configure the concurrency level of XUnit when run through the the `dotnet test` CLI ?

I've followed the advice from this thread: [XUnit dotnet test parallel threads amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72587021/xunit-dotnet-test-parallel-threads-amount)

and created a `xunit.runner.json` file that I believe ends up in the right location, and have specified the `maxParallelThreads`  option found [here](https://xunit.net/docs/configuration-files), but my tests are still being run on the default number of threads.

What am I doing wrong? A minimum repo showing what I've done which doesn't work is here:
https://github.com/keyboardDrummer/concurrencyTestingExperiment

The project contains tests that only pass when all 4 of them are run concurrently, but I can't get them to fail when running them using dotnet test.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is working properly -- I think `maxParallelThreads` just works differently than you're expecting it to.

Check out this [GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/2003), specifically [this comment](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/2003#issuecomment-526730327). I'm not sure what your goals are for concurrency in your tests, but there are some solutions shared there.

##### To see the `maxParallelThreads`

You can see your `maxParallelThreads` observed if you include [`diagnosticMessages`](https://xunit.net/docs/configuration-files#diagnosticMessages) set to `true` in your `xunit.runner.json` and run the tests with verbose console logging:

`dotnet test --logger "console;verbosity=detailed"`